# How to get specif elements from a hidden LSTM sequence inside a model during training

Tags: keras, lstm

I have the following LSTM model

```
 words = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN,))
 x = Embedding(*embedding_matrix.shape, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(words)
 x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_UNITS, return_sequences=True),merge_mode='ave')(x)
 x = Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(LSTM_UNITS, return_sequences=True),merge_mode='ave')(x)
```

What I want is to combine the first and last elements from the sequence returned by the last layer and then feed it into a dense layer. I know that I have some options to aggregate the returned sequence:

```
Using GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x) or GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
Using a TimeDistributed layer to apply a dense layer to each element of the sequence
```

But, as it is a Bidirectional LSTM, maybe the most valuable information is encoded in the extremes, and in the middle are just noise. How can I test this hypothesis and access these two elements?

- Christian

Comment: I think you can just remove `return_sequences=True` from your second LSTM layer and the pass it directly into a `Dense` layer. Just like the example from the docs for `Bidirectional` https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/

Comment: But doing this won't return only one of the extremes (shape=(1,LSTM_UNITS))? How could I verify whether the return, in this case, is some aggregation of both, left and right, contexts of the sequence?

Comment: I believe this would return the final output from the forward LSTM after it reaches the end of the sequence combined with the final result of the backward LSTM after it reaches the beginning of the sequence. So you'd probably want to concatenate these instead of averaging them. I can't find any docs that explicitly cover this case though.